# Date Comparison using Java

Tags: java, date

I have two dates:

1. `toDate` (user input in `MM/dd/yyyy` format)
2. `currentDate` (obtained by `new Date()`)

I need to compare the `currentDate` with `toDate`. I have to display a report only when the `toDate` is equal to or more than `currentDate`. How can I do that?

Comment: Your initial question was honestly said terrible. I've improved it. In the future try to be as clear as possible. Don't repeat things 3 times and/or unnecessarily bold out things :)

Comment: this could help if you consider using joda library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439779/how-to-compare-two-dates-without-the-time-portion

Comment: JodaTime offers so much more than Java's Date API ...  http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/.  It would make this and your other date tasks much easier.

Answer (score 21):

It is easier to compare dates using the `java.util.Calendar`.
Here is what you might do:

```
Calendar toDate = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar nowDate = Calendar.getInstance();
toDate.set(<set-year>,<set-month>,<set-day>);  
if(!toDate.before(nowDate)) {
    //display your report
} else {
    // don't display the report
}
```

Comment: Question: would you need to explicitly clear the hour/minute/etc. fields out of nowDate, or does the fact that they're not set in toDate mean they don't matter?

Comment: +1 for using calendar.  If you're not comparing down near the millisecond level, you usually want to clear() the calendar immediately after you create it, then call the set method.

Comment: i wonder why this isn't accepted yet

Answer (score 11):

If you're set on using Java Dates rather than, say, JodaTime, use a [`java.text.DateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) to convert the string to a Date, then compare the two using .equals:

I almost forgot: You need to zero out the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds on the current date before comparing them.  I used a [`Calendar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object below to do it.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

// Other code here
    String toDate;
    //toDate = "05/11/2010";

    // Value assigned to toDate somewhere in here

    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
    Calendar currDtCal = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Zero out the hour, minute, second, and millisecond
    currDtCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    currDtCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    currDtCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    currDtCal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Date currDt = currDtCal.getTime();

    Date toDt;
    try {
        toDt = df.parse(toDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        toDt = null;
        // Print some error message back to the user
    }

    if (currDt.equals(toDt)) {
        // They're the same date
    }
```

Comment: Fixed some bugs in this... forgot to catch the `ParseException` in the original version.

Answer (score 6):

[`Date#equals()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`Date#after()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29)

If there is a possibility that the `hour` and `minute` fields are != 0, you'd have to set them to 0.

I can't forget to mention that using `java.util.Date` is considered a bad practice, and most of its methods are deprecated. Use `java.util.Calendar` or [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), if possible.

Comment: Given that Date.equals() will be comparing milliseconds and he's comparing the current date to MM/dd/yyyy user input, that's not really a productive approach.

Comment: He wants to compare not check equality.

Comment: If he's converting user-input MM/dd/yyyy data into a Date object, wouldn't the effective time on that object be 0:00 that morning?  Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me this approach will fail if the user enters today's date.

Comment: Yes, but equals() is based on the milliseconds; aren't before() and after() based on it as well?  If toDate is based on MM/dd/yyyy input, he'll also need to manually set the time to one millisecond before midnight of the next day; otherwise, this approach is going to fail if the user enters today's date.  (Won't it?)

Comment: Using Date considered bad practice? By whom?

Comment: @COME FROM:  By Sun.  Check the API; all but the simplest methods are deprecated.

Comment: @BlairHippo: I know about the deprecation and I definitely recognize some of the design flaws of Date. However, you don't need to use the deprecated methods to use the class. The class itself is not deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably looking for:

```
!toDate.before(currentDate)
```

before() and after() test whether the date is strictly before or after. So you have to take the negation of the other one to get non strict behaviour.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but won't this fail if the user enters today's date?  "new Date()" will set the time to whenever it's called, and a Date object based on MM/dd/yyyy will effectively be 0:00 that morning.  Or are Date.before() and Date.after() not based on milliseconds the way Date.equals() is?

Comment: That's right. Actually you have to use Calendar or a DateFormatter to get rid of time in java.util.Date.

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the ways:

```
String toDate = "05/11/2010";

if (new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(toDate).getTime() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) >= System.currentTimeMillis() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) {
    System.out.println("Display report.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Don't display report.");
}
```

A bit more easy interpretable:

```
String toDateAsString = "05/11/2010";
Date toDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(toDateAsString);
long toDateAsTimestamp = toDate.getTime();
long currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
long getRidOfTime = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
long toDateAsTimestampWithoutTime = toDateAsTimestamp / getRidOfTime;
long currentTimestampWithoutTime = currentTimestamp / getRidOfTime;

if (toDateAsTimestampWithoutTime >= currentTimestampWithoutTime) {
    System.out.println("Display report.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Don't display report.");
}
```

Oh, as a bonus, the [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)'s variant:

```
String toDateAsString = "05/11/2010";
DateTime toDate = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy").parseDateTime(toDateAsString);
DateTime now = new DateTime();

if (!toDate.toLocalDate().isBefore(now.toLocalDate())) {
    System.out.println("Display report.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Don't display report.");
}
```

Comment: The first example worked perfectly for my needs :)

Answer (score 3):

Date  `long getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` represented by this Date object.

```
//test if date1 is before date2
if(date1.getTime() < date2.getTime()) {
....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private boolean checkDateLimit() {

    long CurrentDateInMilisecond = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Date 1
    long Date1InMilisecond = Date1.getTimeInMillis(); //Date2

    if (CurrentDateInMilisecond <= Date1InMilisecond) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

// Convert both date into milisecond value .

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you're intent on using `Date` objects for your solution, you'll need to do something like this:

```
    // Convert user input into year, month, and day integers
    Date toDate = new Date(year - 1900, month - 1, day + 1);
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    boolean runThatReport = toDate.after(currentDate);
```

Shifting the `toDate` ahead to midnight of the next day will take care of the bug I've whined about in the comments to other answers.  But, note that this approach uses a deprecated constructor; any approach relying on `Date` will use one deprecated method or another, and depending on how you do it may lead to race conditions as well (if you base `toDate` off of `new Date()` and then fiddle around with the year, month, and day, for instance).  Use `Calendar`, as described elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.Calendar` if you have extensive date related processing.

Date has `before()`, `after()` methods. you could use them as well.