# How to find time is today or yesterday in android

Tags: android, time

I am developing an application for sending SMS. I am storing the current time and showing in the sent history page by retrieving the time from the database. In the sent history page I want to display the time of the message was sent. Here I want to check that the message has been sent today or yesterday or the the day before yesterday like that. If the message was sent yesterday means then I need to display "Yesterday 20:00" like that and even the message was sent yesterday before means "Monday 20:00". I don't know how it has to be done. Please help me if anybody knows.

Comment: please display your code that you have done...

Comment: @Keyser Can you tell me the way to do it?

Comment: Since you haven't tried any code yet, you don't know what help you'll need. Asking a question is premature. Wait until you see what gives you trouble.

Comment: whenever you fetch data from database , fetch last time of conversion in sent box

Comment: @user1498488 Simply find some tutorials on Java date/time handling.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/60861554/5506292

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can do that easily using android.text.format.DateFormat class. Try something like this.

```
public String getFormattedDate(Context context, long smsTimeInMilis) {
    Calendar smsTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    smsTime.setTimeInMillis(smsTimeInMilis);

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    final String timeFormatString = "h:mm aa";
    final String dateTimeFormatString = "EEEE, MMMM d, h:mm aa";
    final long HOURS = 60 * 60 * 60;
    if (now.get(Calendar.DATE) == smsTime.get(Calendar.DATE) ) {
        return "Today " + DateFormat.format(timeFormatString, smsTime);
    } else if (now.get(Calendar.DATE) - smsTime.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1  ){
        return "Yesterday " + DateFormat.format(timeFormatString, smsTime);
    } else if (now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == smsTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
        return DateFormat.format(dateTimeFormatString, smsTime).toString();
    } else {
        return DateFormat.format("MMMM dd yyyy, h:mm aa", smsTime).toString();
    }
}
```

Check http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html for further understanding.

Comment: Are you sure that it is correct? You compare only dates, what about year and month? Today is 20.11.2014, but your code shows "Today" for 20.10.2010

Comment: This answer is not correct. As per documentation, Calendar.DATE is a synonym for DAY_OF_MONTH. Therefore you are not comparing neither the year nor the month.

Comment: Yes, it is not correct. (Calendar.DATE) == smsTime.get(Calendar.DATE) matches only date, not month and year. it returns true for 01.01.2012 and 01.01.2017

Comment: For "today" text this solution is always correct but for "yesterday" text It is not correct in the first day of the month. Method get(Calendar.DATE) returns day of the month and for example 1 - 31 = -30 instead 1 what should display "yesterday" - because 31th of December is the previous day of 1st of January.

Comment: The "today" and "yesterday" needs to include the month and the year in the check, not only the Calendar.DATE

Answer (score 279):

To check if date is today, use Android utils library

```
DateUtils.isToday(long timeInMilliseconds)
```

This utils class also offers human readable strings for relative times. For example,

```
DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(long timeInMilliseconds) -> "42 minutes ago"
```

The are several parameters you can play with to define how precise the time span should be

See [DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html)

Comment: DateUtils.isToday(myDate.getTime()) is working fine, thank you !

Comment: Is this consuming the local (non-UTC) time or UTC-timestamps only?

Comment: `DateUtils.isToday(long millis)` works as described by @Maragues, but be aware, that if you use this method in a piece of code that you want to unit test (like a ViewModel or a Presenter), you will get a RuntimeException when running your tests. This is due to the fact that the android.jar that is used for unit tests does not contain any code. For more info [link](http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked)

Comment: after 24 hour it give yesterday but i want 1 day ago how i can get this kindly guide me about this

Answer (score 110):

As mentioned, `DateUtils.isToday(d.getTime())` will work for determining if `Date d` is today. But some responses here don't actually answer how to determine if a date was yesterday. You can also do that easily with `DateUtils`:

```
public static boolean isYesterday(Date d) {
    return DateUtils.isToday(d.getTime() + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
}
```

Following that, you could also determine if a date was tomorrow:

```
public static boolean isTomorrow(Date d) {
    return DateUtils.isToday(d.getTime() - DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simple to read, and effective. Only way to make it even more effective would be to write the methods for a millis timestamp, so one can use it with Calendar, Date or whatever class you prefer.

Comment: This is great. But for some weird reason I'm not able to use this as an extension function in Kotlin like: `fun DateUtils.isYesterday(d: Long): Boolean { return DateUtils.isToday(d + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS) }`

Comment: i think this is best solution in literally two lines of code it gets the job done

Answer (score 22):

For today you can use `DateUtils.isToday` from [android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#isToday(long)).

For yesterday you can use that code:

```
public static boolean isYesterday(long date) {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cdate = Calendar.getInstance();
    cdate.setTimeInMillis(date);

    now.add(Calendar.DATE,-1);

    return now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cdate.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        && now.get(Calendar.MONTH) == cdate.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        && now.get(Calendar.DATE) == cdate.get(Calendar.DATE);
}
```

Comment: @lujpo perfection!

Comment: The above code with now.get(Calendar.MONTH) seems to return the previous month!?

Comment: @tina it should only happen at first day of month

Answer (score 13):

---

### NO libs used

---

**Yesterday**

**Today**

**Tomorrow**

**This year**

**Any year**

```
 public static String getMyPrettyDate(long neededTimeMilis) {
    Calendar nowTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar neededTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    neededTime.setTimeInMillis(neededTimeMilis);

    if ((neededTime.get(Calendar.YEAR) == nowTime.get(Calendar.YEAR))) {

        if ((neededTime.get(Calendar.MONTH) == nowTime.get(Calendar.MONTH))) {

            if (neededTime.get(Calendar.DATE) - nowTime.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1) {
                //here return like "Tomorrow at 12:00"
                return "Tomorrow at " + DateFormat.format("HH:mm", neededTime);

            } else if (nowTime.get(Calendar.DATE) == neededTime.get(Calendar.DATE)) {
                //here return like "Today at 12:00"
                return "Today at " + DateFormat.format("HH:mm", neededTime);

            } else if (nowTime.get(Calendar.DATE) - neededTime.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1) {
                //here return like "Yesterday at 12:00"
                return "Yesterday at " + DateFormat.format("HH:mm", neededTime);

            } else {
                //here return like "May 31, 12:00"
                return DateFormat.format("MMMM d, HH:mm", neededTime).toString();
            }

        } else {
            //here return like "May 31, 12:00"
            return DateFormat.format("MMMM d, HH:mm", neededTime).toString();
        }

    } else {
        //here return like "May 31 2010, 12:00" - it's a different year we need to show it
        return DateFormat.format("MMMM dd yyyy, HH:mm", neededTime).toString();
    }
}
```

**Kotlin extension function:**

```
fun Long.toPrettyDate(): String {
    val nowTime = Calendar.getInstance()
    val neededTime = Calendar.getInstance()
    neededTime.timeInMillis = this
    
    return if (neededTime[Calendar.YEAR] == nowTime[Calendar.YEAR]) {
        if (neededTime[Calendar.MONTH] == nowTime[Calendar.MONTH]) {
            when {
                neededTime[Calendar.DATE] - nowTime[Calendar.DATE] == 1 -> {
                    //here return like "Tomorrow at 12:00"
                    "Tomorrow at " +  SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date(this))
                }
                nowTime[Calendar.DATE] == neededTime[Calendar.DATE] -> {
                    //here return like "Today at 12:00"
                    "Today at " +  SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date(this))
                }
                nowTime[Calendar.DATE] - neededTime[Calendar.DATE] == 1 -> {
                    //here return like "Yesterday at 12:00"
                    "Yesterday at " +  SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date(this))
                }
                else -> {
                    //here return like "May 31, 12:00"
                    SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date(this))
                }
            }
        } else {
            //here return like "May 31, 12:00"
            SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date(this))
        }
    } else {
        //here return like "May 31 2022, 12:00" - it's a different year we need to show it
        SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy, HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date(this))
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the code it really helped!
it just have a minor issue that the condition for "Yesterday at " and ""Tomorrow at" are the same!
the ""Tomorrow at" one should be -1 instead

Comment: have you considered that tomorrow or yesterday can be in a different month?

Answer (score 10):

If your API level is 26 or higher, then you better use LocalDate class:

```
fun isToday(whenInMillis: Long): Boolean {
    return LocalDate.now().compareTo(LocalDate(whenInMillis)) == 0
}

fun isTomorrow(whenInMillis: Long): Boolean {
    return LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).compareTo(LocalDate(whenInMillis)) == 0
}

fun isYesterday(whenInMillis: Long): Boolean {
    return LocalDate.now().minusDays(1).compareTo(LocalDate(whenInMillis)) == 0
}
```

If your app has lower API level, use

```
fun isToday(whenInMillis: Long): Boolean {
    return DateUtils.isToday(whenInMillis)
}

fun isTomorrow(whenInMillis: Long): Boolean {
    return DateUtils.isToday(whenInMillis - DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS)
}

fun isYesterday(whenInMillis: Long): Boolean {
    return DateUtils.isToday(whenInMillis + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try this:

```
Calendar mDate = Calendar.getInstance(); // just for example
if (DateUtils.isToday(mDate.getTimeInMillis())) {
  //format one way
} else {
  //format in other way
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Blow snippet useful in recycler view header section.

Kotlin Extension:

```
fun Date.isYesterday(): Boolean = DateUtils.isToday(this.time + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS)

fun Date.isToday(): Boolean = DateUtils.isToday(this.time)


fun Date.toDateString(): String {
   return when {
    this.isToday() -> {
        "Today"
    }
    this.isYesterday() -> {
        "Yesterday"
    }
    else -> {
        convetedDate.format(this)
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it. In **kotlin** with recommended lib **ThreeTen**

1. Add ThreeTen

   ```
   implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.1.0'
   ```
2. Add kotlin extensions.

   ```
   fun LocalDate.isYesterday(): Boolean = this.isEqual(LocalDate.now().minusDays(1L))

   fun LocalDate.isToday(): Boolean = this.isEqual(LocalDate.now())
   ```

Comment: This should be the way to go. Custom parsing is just bad.

Answer (score 5):

### Kotlin

@Choletski solution but with seconds and in Kotlin

```
 fun getMyPrettyDate(neededTimeMilis: Long): String? {
        val nowTime = Calendar.getInstance()
        val neededTime = Calendar.getInstance()
        neededTime.timeInMillis = neededTimeMilis
        return if (neededTime[Calendar.YEAR] == nowTime[Calendar.YEAR]) {
            if (neededTime[Calendar.MONTH] == nowTime[Calendar.MONTH]) {
                if (neededTime[Calendar.DATE] - nowTime[Calendar.DATE] == 1) {
                    //here return like "Tomorrow at 12:00"
                    "Tomorrow at " + DateFormat.format("HH:mm:ss", neededTime)
                } else if (nowTime[Calendar.DATE] == neededTime[Calendar.DATE]) {
                    //here return like "Today at 12:00"
                    "Today at " + DateFormat.format("HH:mm:ss", neededTime)
                } else if (nowTime[Calendar.DATE] - neededTime[Calendar.DATE] == 1) {
                    //here return like "Yesterday at 12:00"
                    "Yesterday at " + DateFormat.format("HH:mm:ss", neededTime)
                } else {
                    //here return like "May 31, 12:00"
                    DateFormat.format("MMMM d, HH:mm:ss", neededTime).toString()
                }
            } else {
                //here return like "May 31, 12:00"
                DateFormat.format("MMMM d, HH:mm:ss", neededTime).toString()
            }
        } else {
            //here return like "May 31 2010, 12:00" - it's a different year we need to show it
            DateFormat.format("MMMM dd yyyy, HH:mm:ss", neededTime).toString()
        }
    }
```

You can pass here `date.getTime()` to get outputs like

```
Today at 18:34:45
Yesterday at 12:30:00
Tomorrow at 09:04:05
```

Answer (score 3):

Also quite pretty using as kotlin extension:

```
fun Calendar.isToday() : Boolean {
    val today = Calendar.getInstance()
    return today[Calendar.YEAR] == get(Calendar.YEAR) && today[Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR] == get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)
}
```

And using:

```
if (calendar.isToday()) {
    Log.d("Calendar", "isToday")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is method for get Values like Today , Yesterday and Date like Whtsapp app have**

```
public String getSmsTodayYestFromMilli(long msgTimeMillis) {

        Calendar messageTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        messageTime.setTimeInMillis(msgTimeMillis);
        // get Currunt time
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        final String strTimeFormate = "h:mm aa";
        final String strDateFormate = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm aa";

        if (now.get(Calendar.DATE) == messageTime.get(Calendar.DATE)
                &&
                ((now.get(Calendar.MONTH) == messageTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)))
                &&
                ((now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == messageTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
                ) {

            return "today at " + DateFormat.format(strTimeFormate, messageTime);

        } else if (
                ((now.get(Calendar.DATE) - messageTime.get(Calendar.DATE)) == 1)
                        &&
                        ((now.get(Calendar.MONTH) == messageTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)))
                        &&
                        ((now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == messageTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
                ) {
            return "yesterday at " + DateFormat.format(strTimeFormate, messageTime);
        } else {
            return "date : " + DateFormat.format(strDateFormate, messageTime);
        }
    }
```

**Use this method just pass Millisecond like**

```
 getSmsTodayYestFromMilli(Long.parseLong("1485236534000"));
```

Comment: Did you test this code on your side or any reference?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    long secs = (dateToCompare - now.getTime().getTime()) / 1000;
    if (secs > 0) {
        int hours = (int) secs / 3600;
        if (hours <= 24) {
            return today + "," + "a formatted day or empty";
        } else if (hours <= 48) {
            return yesterday + "," + "a formatted day or empty";
        }
    } else {
        int hours = (int) Math.abs(secs) / 3600;

        if (hours <= 24) {
            return tommorow + "," + "a formatted day or empty";
        }
    }
    return "a formatted day or empty";
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin

**Result:**

> Today's Date --> **Today**
>
> Yesterday Date -> **Yesterday**
>
> This Year Date -> **20 Jun**
>
> Not This Year Date -> **01 Feb 2019**

```
fun Context.toReadableDateFormat(date: Long, comparableDate: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()): String{
   val comparableDateTime = comparableDate.getCalendar()
   val itemDateTime = date.getCalendar()
   return if(
    comparableDateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == itemDateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) &&
    comparableDateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH) == itemDateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH) &&
    comparableDateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR) == itemDateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)
)
       "Today"
   else if(isYesterday(date).orFalse())
       "Yesterday"
   else if(comparableDateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR) == itemDateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR))
       itemDateTime.toFormat("dd MMM")
   else
       itemDateTime.toFormat("dd MMM yyyy")
```

}

To check yesterday

```
fun isYesterday(date: Long, comparableDate: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()): Boolean {
   val comparableDateTime = comparableDate.getCalendar()
   val itemDateTime = date.getCalendar()
   comparableDateTime.add(Calendar.DATE, -1)
   return comparableDateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) ==
        itemDateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) &&
        comparableDateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH) ==
        itemDateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH) &&
        comparableDateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR) ==
        itemDateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR) 
}



fun Long.getCalendar() = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
   timeInMillis = this@getCalendar
}
```

To call above function use this syntax

```
context.toReadableDateFormat(1687342714503) // your date in timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

i can suggest you one thing. When u send the sms store the details into a database so that u can display the date and time on which the sms was sent in the history page.

Comment: Yes iam storing the time in the database. But i need to check whether the stored time is today or yesterday or yesterday before like that.

Comment: if ur storing the time.then why cant u store he date also?

Comment: Yes i can but I need to show like "Today 8:00" like that in the textview

Comment: U can do that... get the date from the Db and compare with todays date.if the it matches then display a text view as "Today" if it is current date - revious date then display "Yesterday"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811121/date-comparison-using-java
http://java2everyone.blogspot.in/2009/02/compare-current-date-with-user-input.html
http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/CompareDate.shtml

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17814/discussion-between-user1498488-and-goofy)

Answer (score 0):

`DateUtils.isToday()` should be considered deprecated because `android.text.format.Time` is now deprecated. 
Until they update the source code for isToday, there is no solution here that detects today, yesterday, handles shifts to/from daylight saving time, and does not use deprecated code. Here it is in Kotlin, using a `today` field that must be kept up to date periodically (e.g. `onResume` etc):

```
@JvmStatic
fun dateString(ctx: Context, epochTime: Long): String {
    val epochMS = 1000*epochTime
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.timeInMillis = epochMS
    val yearDiff = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - today.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    if (yearDiff == 0) {
        if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) >= today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR))
            return ctx.getString(R.string.today)
    }
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
    if (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) == today.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
        if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR))
            return ctx.getString(R.string.yesterday)
    }
    val flags = if (yearDiff == 0) DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH else DateUtils.FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE
    return DateUtils.formatDateTime(ctx, epochMS, flags)
}
```

I filed https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=227694&thanks=227694&ts=1479155729, go vote on it

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up with for now:

```
import android.text.format.DateFormat

fun java.util.Date.asPrettyTime(context: Context): String {
    val nowTime = Calendar.getInstance()

    val dateTime = Calendar.getInstance().also { calendar ->
        calendar.timeInMillis = this.time
    }

    if (dateTime[Calendar.YEAR] != nowTime[Calendar.YEAR]) { // different year
        return DateFormat.format("MM.dd.yyyy.  ·  HH:mm", dateTime).toString()
    }

    if (dateTime[Calendar.MONTH] != nowTime[Calendar.MONTH]) { // different month
        return DateFormat.format("MM.dd.  ·  HH:mm", dateTime).toString()
    }

    return when {
        nowTime[Calendar.DATE] == dateTime[Calendar.DATE] -> { // today
            "${context.getString(R.string.today)}  ·  ${DateFormat.format("HH:mm", dateTime)}"
        }
        nowTime[Calendar.DATE] - dateTime[Calendar.DATE] == 1 -> { // yesterday
            "${context.getString(R.string.yesterday)}  ·  ${DateFormat.format("HH:mm", dateTime)}"
        }
        nowTime[Calendar.DATE] - dateTime[Calendar.DATE] == -1 -> { // tomorrow
            "${context.getString(R.string.tomorrow)}  ·  ${DateFormat.format("HH:mm", dateTime)}"
        }
        else -> { // other date this month
            DateFormat.format("MM.dd.  ·  HH:mm", dateTime).toString()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that I use:

```
public static boolean isTomorrow(Calendar c) {
    Calendar tomorrow = Calendar.getInstance();
    tomorrow.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    return (tomorrow.get(Calendar.YEAR) == c.get(Calendar.YEAR)) && (tomorrow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)));
}

public static boolean isToday(Calendar c) {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    return (today.get(Calendar.YEAR) == c.get(Calendar.YEAR)) && (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
}
```

**This covers all the edge-cases that may occur.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer as per my needs. Just sharing incase some else may find useful. My code works even if yesterday or tomorrow was or is respectively in a different month or year. Enjoy !

```
 fun getAppropriateStringFromDueDate(dueDate: Date): String {

    val timeFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
    val dateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm")
    val time = timeFormatter.format(dueDate)

    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.time = todayDate
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
    val timeDifference = dueDate.time - calendar.timeInMillis
    val aDayInMillis = DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS
    val twoDaysInMillis = 2 * aDayInMillis
    return when(timeDifference) {
        in 0L..< aDayInMillis -> "Today, $time"
        in aDayInMillis..<twoDaysInMillis ->  "Tomorrow, $time"
        in -aDayInMillis..<0L ->  "Yesterday, $time"
        else -> dateFormatter.format(dueDate)
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Without any library and simple code, work on every Kotlin project

```
//Simple date format of the day
val sdfDate = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")

//Create this 2 extensions of Date
fun Date.isToday() = sdfDate.format(this) == sdfDate.format(Date())
fun Date.isYesterday() =
    sdfDate.format(this) == sdfDate.format(Calendar.getInstance().apply { 
          add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1) }.time)
 
    
//And after everwhere in your code you can do
if(myDate.isToday()){
   ...
}
else if(myDate.isYesterday()) {
...
}
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27297702).