# Java Resultset - Compare java date with SQL getDate()

Tags: java, swing, datetime, resultset

Codes for getting current date:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date now = new Date();
String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
return strDate;
```

Codes to search date and return result

```
try
   {     
        String x = cDate();

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(fill);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        int count = 0;

       while (rs.next()){
       Date dDate = rs.getDate("recDate");

        if (x.equals(dDate)){
            System.out.println("True);
            break;
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("False");
            }
        }

   }
   catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
  }
```

Codes below to search names and return result

```
   try
   {     
        string attendant = txtName.getText();

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(fill);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        int count = 0;

       while (rs.next()){
       String bName = rs.getString("name");

        if (attendant.equals(bName){
            System.out.println("True);
            break;
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("False");
            }
        }

   }
   catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
  }
```

I manged to get my 2nd code which is to search name and return result to work nicely. But as for the date search, it result false even I have the getDate() in SQL DB.

I did a System.out.println(x) and System.out.println(dDate) to verify the format but it turn out to be correct.

2013-01-17
2013-01-17

which should return "True"

Edited:

```
        java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(now.getTime());

       I replace (x.equals(dDate)) to (sqlDate == dDate) but the result still return as false, any idea?
```

Please help..

Finally I got it..

Solution

```
       (Math.round(now.getTime() / 1000/3600/24) == Math.round(dDate.getTime() /1000/3600/24)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Date contains time information also. Dates could differ in minutes or even seconds. To make sure both dates has exactly the same value you should print out `date.getTime()` which return `long` value of milliseconds since `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT`. If you wanna compare you should convert `x` from String to Date and then do this:

```
  x.getTime() == dDate.getTime()
```

however, if you wanna compare just year, month and day you should trunk like this:

```
  Math.round(x.getTime()/1000/3600/24) == Math.round(dDate.getTime()/1000/3600/24)
```

More about Date comparision in Java you can find here: [Date Comparison using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811121/date-comparison-using-java)

Comment: I realised (Math.round(now.getTime() / 1000/3600/24) == Math.round(dDate.getTime() /1000/3600/24) doesn't do the comparison. It just return the results of the names. e.g 17th Jan is today but results includes 16th Jan. Any idea?

Comment: Can't be. It should compare dates within same day. You're truncating by 1000 (milliseconds in second) 3600 (seconds in hour) 24 (hours in day)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because you are trying to compare a String with a date object which is going to be false although the values are same but both are different objects.

```
String x = cDate();
...
Date dDate = rs.getDate("recDate");
...
if(x.equals(dDate)){
```

The default behavior of `equals` method compares whether object references are pointing to the same object and not based on the values.

Comment: java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date();
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(now.getTime());

       I replace (x.equals(dDate)) to (sqlDate == dDate) but the result still return as false, any idea?

Comment: it is because your variables `sqlDate` and `now` are referring to different objects and `==` checks if both the variables are referring to same object or not, `==` doesn't check for value.

Answer (score 1):

At the line :

```
x.equals(dDate)
```

x is a `String`, and dDate is a `java.sql.Date`.
They are not equals.