# How to compare just the day in a java date?

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to do a simple date comparison between yesterday and today

```
if (yesterday.before(today)) {
 ...
}
```

The issue is that with the before method I will eval to true even if it's just a few seconds difference. How might I compare just the day (because I only want to eval this to true if it was the previous day (minutes/seconds should be ignored)

Thank you in advance

Comment: compare between date in java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar

Comment: I'm surprised there's no easy way to do this using the standard API. If you can't use commons lang for some reason (as per Lobo), I suggest you convert each Date to a number of days since the epoch (i.e. `millisSinceEpoch / MILLIS_IN_DAY`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

using [DateUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html) -

```
if (!DateUtils.isSameDay(yesterday, today) && (yesterday.before(today)) {
   //...
}
```

EDIT: it can be done without DateUtils as well. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439779/how-to-compare-two-dates-without-the-time-portion) thread.

Comment: awesome! what is the artifact id for this repo so I can add it using mvn?

Comment: @Toran Billups - I'm not sure but google search turned up `<artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>`. never worked with maven.

Comment: For anyone else this url helped me add the commons-lang to maven http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.3

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use a 3rd party library implement a method like this:

```
public boolean before(Calendar yesterday, Calendar today) {
    if(yesterday == today) return false;
    if(yesterday == null || today == null) return false;
    return  yesterday.get(Calendar.YEAR) < today.get(Calendar.YEAR) ? true : 
        yesterday.get(Calendar.YEAR) == today.get(Calendar.YEAR) && yesterday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're up to adding a library that handles dates better than the standard Java libraries, you might want to look at [Joda](http://joda.sourceforge.net/).

Using Joda, you can compute difference between days by:

```
  Days d = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate);
  int days = d.getDays();
```

where `startDate` and `endDate` are the Joda version of dates, `DateTime` (actually a superclass of that).

Converting Java `Date` objects to Joda `DateTime` objects can be done by a constructor call:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(javaDate);
```

Adding this library may be overkill for this specific problem, but if you deal with date and time manipulation a lot, the library is definitely worth it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick to `Date` you could temporarily lower your current date by one day. If `before()` still leads to the same result you have a timespan of at least one day.

```
final static long DAY_MILLIS = 86400000;

Date d1 = new Date(2011, 06, 18);
Date d2 = new Date(2011, 06, 16);

Date temp = new Date(d1.getTime() - DAY_MILLIS);

if (temp.before(d2)) 
  // Do stuff
}
```

Please note I used a deprecated constructor but it should do the job.