# Compare only the time portion of two dates, ignoring the date part

Tags: java, datetime, date, time

What's a good method to, given two Date objects, compare the difference between their time portion only, completely ignoring Year, Month and Day?

It's quite the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439779/how-to-compare-two-dates-without-the-time-portion).

**UPDATE:** Here's the final code for future reference:

```
private long differenceBetween(Date currentTime, Date timeToRun)
{
    Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentCal.setTime(currentTime);

    Calendar runCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    runCal.setTime(timeToRun);
    runCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, currentCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    runCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentCal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    runCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, currentCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    return currentCal.getTimeInMillis() - runCal.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: The irony of this solution is that you take two objects that are thin wrappers around a primitive of type long, invoke a massive and complex API to convert from longs to Calendar objects ... only to end up back at a place where you're converting from Calendar objects to longs again.

Comment: @scottb - See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676149#7676307) below, which does not mess with `Calendar` objects but uses only the `Date` members.

Comment: **Update** Nowadays, we can [do this in a one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53027248/642706) with the *java.time* classes that supplanted the terrible `Date` & `Calendar`. Much easier, much cleaner, and with proper handling of time zones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Duration                                  // Span of time, with resolution of nanoseconds.
.between(                                 // Calculate elapsed time.
    LocalTime.now(                        // Get current time-of-day…
        ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )   // … as seen in a particular time zone.
    )                                     // Returns a `LocalTime` object.
    ,
    myJavaUtilDate                        // Avoid terrible legacy date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`.
    .toInstant()                          // Convert from `java.util.Date` to `java.time.Instant`, both representing a moment in UTC.
    .atZone(                              // Adjust from UTC to a particular time zone. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
        ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )   // Specify time zone by proper naming in `Continent/Region` format, never 2-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `PST`, `CEST`, `CST`, `IST`, etc.
    )                                     // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .toLocalTime()                        // Extract the time-of-day without the date and without a time zone.
)                                         // Returns a `Duration` object.
.toMillis()                               // Calculate entire span-of-time in milliseconds. Beware of data-loss as `Instant` uses a finer resolution the milliseconds, and may carry microseconds or nanoseconds.
```

I suggest passing around the type-safe and self-explanatory `Duration` object rather than a mere integer number of milliseconds.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the terrible legacy classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`.

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

Convert your `java.util.Date` (a moment in UTC), to an `Instant`. Use new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

That represents a moment in UTC. Determining a date and a time-of-day requires a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) . For any given moment, the date and time vary around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Assign the `ZoneId` to the `Instant` to produce a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the time-of-day portion, without the date and without the time zone.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
```

Compare. Calculate elapsed time with a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

```
Duration d = Duration.between( ltStart , ltStop ) ;
```

Be aware that **this is not a fair comparison**. Days are not always 24-hours long, and not all time-of-day values are valid on all days in all zones. For example, in the United States during a Daylight Saving Time cutover, there may not be a 2 AM hour at all. So 1 AM to 4 AM may be 3 hours on one date but only 2 hours on another date.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 32):

If you want to compare the underlying binary (long int) values of the dates, you can do this:

```
public int compareTimes(Date d1, Date d2)
{
    int     t1;
    int     t2;

    t1 = (int) (d1.getTime() % (24*60*60*1000L));
    t2 = (int) (d2.getTime() % (24*60*60*1000L));
    return (t1 - t2);
}
```

**Addendum 1**

This technique has the advantage of speed, because it uses the underlying `long` value of the `Date` objects directly, instead of converting between ticks and calendar components (which is rather expensive and slow). It's also a lot simpler than messing with `Calendar` objects.

**Addendum 2**

The code above returns the time difference as an `int`, which will be correct for any pair of times, since it ignores the year/month/day portions of the dates entirely, and the difference between any two times is no more than 86,400,000 ms (= 1000 ms/sec × 60 sec/min × 60 min/hr × 24 hr/day).

Comment: This is the best answer, imo.  There is no need to use a complex Calendar API to compare time values within Date objects.

Comment: this is perfect and smart

Comment: thnx david, exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: Very nice! Gooooooood!

Comment: This does not always work. Example: currentDate: Tue Oct 20 16:28:57 MESZ 2015 and validFromTime: Tue Oct 20 01:30:00 MESZ 2015 returns the wrong result.

Comment: @confile I think you're mistaken. This here is supposed to just compare the 24 hours passed from 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970. If you calculate the module with any `long` value  with `% (24*60*60*1000L)` you're only left with the number of milliseconds that "*fit*" into 24 hours.

Comment: Be careful with daylight saving time, when one date is in DST and the other is not, the calculation is off by one hour. If both dates are in the same timezone everything is OK.

Comment: @mabi: The internal ticks count returned by `getTime()` is not aware of, nor affected by DST. If two tick values are equal, they represent the same point in time (the number of msec ticks since the UTC epoch), regardless of the calendar, timezone, or DST setting object they are enclosed within.

Comment: @DavidRTribble what is the expected result of comparing 2 February 17:00 and 2 August 17:00? I think it should be zero. This is not the result I get.

Comment: `getTime()` GMT based time stamp which may not be suitable for some cases, as if you are living in -1 time zone and you have to compare 22 hours with 23 hours, apparently 22 hours are less than 23 hours but due to time zone difference `hetTime()` will conert 22 hours to 23 hours and 23 hours to 0 hours and than 23 hours becomes greater than 0 hours.

Comment: @RehanHaider I had this issue. But with a little tweak in the code, I think the case can be handled.

Comment: I don't believe this Answer addresses the Question, the rather unclear Question. But, besides that, no need to roll-your-own date-time math in modern Java to calculate elapsed milliseconds between two moments: `Duration.between( d1.toInstant() , d2.toInstant() ).toMillis()`

Answer (score 21):

You may consider using Joda time's `DateTimeComparator.getTimeOnlyInstance()` for a comparator that will compare two Joda dates based only upon the times.

For example:

```
DateTimeComparator comparator = DateTimeComparator.getTimeOnlyInstance();
comparator.compare(date1, date2);
```

See [http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeComparator.html#getTimeOnlyInstance()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeComparator.html#getTimeOnlyInstance%28%29)

Comment: If (java) time is the question, JODA is the answer :D

Comment: @bbaja42 Not is you use GWT :/

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class.  It has support for extracting hours, minutes, and seconds from given `Date`'s.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(yourDateObject);
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Comment: Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY is more appropriate (24 hours rather than 12)

Answer (score 4):

In case you can't use JODA,

create 2 calendar objects, set year, month and day to 0.

Compare them....

Answer (score 2):

Dont know how good practiced or efficent is this one but i've written a simple function using the Date object that serves my purposes. It returns a true or false is the first date value bigger than the second. The inputs d1 && d2 are Date objects.

```
function CompareTimes(d1, d2) {
             if (d1.getHours() < d2.getHours()) {
                 return false;
             }
             if (d1.getHours() > d2.getHours()) {
                 return true;

             } else {
                 return (d1.getMinutes() > d2.getMinutes());
             }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If JODA is not an option, one of the shortest approaches is probably to convert the time to strings and then compare them.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmssSZ");
df.format(date1).equals(df.format(date2));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to compare the time part of the dates then this would give you the right result -

```
public long compareTimes(Date d1, Date d2)
    {
        long     t1;
        long     t2;
        t1 = d1.getHours()*60*60+d1.getMinutes()*60+d1.getSeconds();
        t2 = d2.getHours()*60*60+d2.getMinutes()*60+d2.getSeconds();
        long diff = t1-t2;
        System.out.println("t1 - "+t1+", t2 - "+t2+",  diff - "+diff);

        return diff;
    }
```