# Compare two dates by date portion only, not time

Tags: java

i don't want to compare year, months and days...it can affect the performance...is there any api for direct comparison ?

```
Date date1 = new Date(d1.getYear()  d1.getMonth(), d1.getDate());
Date date2 = new Date(d2.getYear(), d2.getMonth(), d2.getDate());
date1.compareTo(date2);
```

Comment: By how much does it actually affect the performance?

Comment: Comparing year, month, and date directly is going to be much faster than what any other api does, if you don't code for all the fringe cases.

Comment: All the dates in java are basically no of millisecond after a fix date, so i think simply comparing the miliseconds should be easy and straightforward, rather than doing all sort of formatting to compare.

Comment: @gyan the compareTo for date is likely implemented with millis

Comment: Create your own comparator...

Comment: @crush How? by comparing years, months, days?

Comment: Something like `Comparator<Date> myComparator = new Comparator<Date>() { public void compare(Date a, Date b) { return a.getDate() == b.getDate() ? 0 : a.getDate() > b.getDate() ? 1 : -1; };` I guess...not that this is necessary to achieve his goal. It's just an option. Definitely not the best one.

Answer (score 3):

[Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) has [before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29) and [after](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29) methods.

Comment: Does `compareTo(date2)` not compare the year, month, and date?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `compare or compareTo` method Read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367936/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-java) which will answer you