# Calculate the difference between two dates, "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, methods, difference

I want to use the `difference` method.
It gets a certain date parameter, then calculates the difference between two dates (this and other)

The `calculateDate` is the way to get the days passed since the Christian counting. I wanted to use it inside the `difference` method, but I get the following error while trying to compile:

> cannot find symbol - variable calculateDate

The difference has to be an absolute value, so I added the `Math.abs`.

```
public int difference (Date other) {
            return Math.abs(this.calculateDate-other.calculateDate);
}

//computes the day number since the beginning of the Christian counting of years
private int calculateDate (int day, int month, int year)
{
    if (month < 3)
    {
        year--;
        month = month + 12;
    }
    return 365 * year + year/4 - year/100 + year/400 + ((month+1) * 306)/10 + (day - 62);

}
```

Comment: `calculateDate` is not a variable. Its a method that is taking three parameters

Comment: If you want call a method, then you need to supply arguments.

Comment: from the looks of it, `calculateDate(...)` is a method, expecting three `int`s, but you use it as if it were a attribute: `this.calculateDate`

Comment: so what should I do in order to be able to proceed?

Comment: @Idosud: Do what you've been told: Supply appropriate arguments to your calls of `calculateDate`. That is the day, the month and the year of `this` and `other`, respectively. Or consider rewriting `calculateDate` to return the number of days for the current instance, so you can just call it with no arguments (but you'll still need to write a pair of parenthesis, but without anything between them).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to compare two dates in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367936/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use `java.time` library instead of writing the day counting code by hand, unless you have a very specific requirement:

```
private int difference(LocalDate date) {
  LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(0, 1, 1); // 1 Jan 0000 
  return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, date); 
}
```

You can map from `java.util.Date` to `java.time.LocalDate` with:

```
Date date = ...
LocalDate ld = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

Comment: As you said, I have a very specific requirement. In that case, what should I do?