# How can I compare two Calendar dates?

Tags: java, date, calendar, comparison

I have a Java problem where I need to check if an item has expired. This is supposed to check if the item is at least x (x is an integer and can be set to any integer value) months old.

Just to reclarify Supposing I have a pack of eggs, I want to check if it has been 1 months since I added them (`dateAdded`).

I wrote a simple comparison but it doesn't seem to give the correct response.  Here is the code.

```
public Boolean isEndOfLine() {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    if(today.compareTo(dateAdded) >= END_OF_LINE) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The value of end of line is an integer 12 i.e 12 months.

Comment: can be simplified: return today.compareTo(dateAdded) >= END_OF_LINE;

Comment: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ - A nice library for dealing with dates and times in Java. Better than using Calendar and Date. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764106/comparing-two-dates-using-joda-time

Comment: what is END_OF_LINE? compareTo returns -1, 0 or 1...

Comment: You must first specify what you actually want to check. "Older than x months" is a colloquial condition, which cannot be expressed precisely in any programming language. Do you consider a month to be 28, 29, 30 or 31 days? Do you want to consider the time of day? If so, do you have to consider time zone changes like DST?

Comment: END_OF_LINE is an integer specifying how many months back to compare to

Comment: @BenjaminDale: What exact advantage would Joda bring when solving this particular problem?

Comment: @jarnbjo I guess in this case, it's not necessary, but I thought i'd make OP aware of such a library if they didn't already know. It's helpful and has many built in methods for this type of thing.

Comment: @BenjaminDale: Sure, you can use Joda to compare dates, just as you can use the standard API to compare dates. What's the advantage of Joda when solving exactly this problem?

Comment: Did you read the first sentence of my response? "I guess in this case, it's not necessary, but I thought i'd make OP aware of such a library if they didn't already know." There's absolutely 100% nothing wrong with using the standard API.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Doesn't give the correct response. 

I cannot use the Date Class only the GregorianCalendar class.

Comment: What about using LWUIT in this code to make the comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not hold javadoc in my head, but along the lines of:

```
dateAdded.add(Calendar.Month, END_OF_LINE).compareTo(today) > 0
```

Comment: My upvote because this considers the OPs statement/comment about END_OF_LINE as integer tracking the past months although I am not quite sure if END_OF_LINE should be added to today instead. But the question is not very clear. And note, compareTo() is here only an instant comparison so this is okay for the specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some similar example code, but using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library.

FYI:

- A Joda-Time [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) instance knows its own time zone.
- The [`minusMonths`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#minusMonths%28int%29) method is smart, handles [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) and other issues. You may want to read its source code to verify its logic follows your business rules as to what "x number of months ago" means.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

// Better to specify a time zone explicitly rather than rely on default.
// Time Zone list… http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html  (not quite up-to-date, read page for details)
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );

int countMonths = 2;

DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );
// If you want to include the entire day, get first moment of the day by calling "withTimeAtStartOfDay".
DateTime someMonthsAgo = now.minusMonths( countMonths ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime dateAdded = new DateTime( 2013, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, timeZone  ); // Arbitrary values for example.

// If 'dateAdded' happened prior to our target date-time 'someMonthsAgo', the pack of eggs is expired.
Boolean isEndOfLine = dateAdded.isBefore( someMonthsAgo );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "someMonthsAgo: " + someMonthsAgo );
System.out.println( "dateAdded: " + dateAdded );
System.out.println( "isEndOfLine: " + isEndOfLine );
```

When run…

```
now: 2014-01-08T21:36:11.179+01:00
someMonthsAgo: 2013-11-08T00:00:00.000+01:00
dateAdded: 2013-05-06T07:08:09.000+02:00
isEndOfLine: true
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the  [Calendar docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) 
You should not rely on the number returned by compareTo - you just know that if it is greater than 0 that the original date is greater.

So create a new date (x months in the passed) and compare to that one.

Answer (score 0):

The method returns 0 if the time represented by the argument is equal to the time represented by this Calendar object; or a value less than 0 if the time of this Calendar is before the time represented by the argument; or a value greater than 0 if the time of this Calendar is after the time represented.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class CalendarDemo {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

          // create two calendar at the different dates
          Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 8, 15);
          Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar(2008, 1, 02);

          // compare the time values represented by two calendar objects.
          int i = cal1.compareTo(cal2);

          // return positive value if equals else return negative value
          System.out.println("The result is :"+i);

          // compare again but with the two calendars swapped
          int j = cal2.compareTo(cal);

          // return positive value if equals else return negative value
          System.out.println("The result is :" + j);

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution. Tested with JUNIT to confirm results.

```
public Boolean isEndOfLine() {
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    today.add(Calendar.MONTH, -END_OF_LINE);
    return today.compareTo(dateAdded) >= 0;
}
```

I subtracted the `END_OF_LINE` from today using the add method. Notice the minus on line 3. I then compared to see if it is greater than 0. Thanks for all your suggestions.