# Compare current date with date from property file

Tags: java, date

I am getting a hard coded date from the property file , which is of the format `dd-MMM-yyyy`.

Now i need to compare it with current date of same format. For that purpose , i cooked up this piece of code :

```
Date convDate = new Date();
Date currentFormattedDate = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
convDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse("20-Aug-2013");
currentFormattedDate = new Date(dateFormat.format(currentFormattedDate)); 
if(currentFormattedDate.after(convDate) || currentFormattedDate.equals(convDate)){
  System.out.println("Correct");
}else{
  System.out.println("In correct");
}
```

But eclipse tells me that `new Date` has been depreciated. Does any one know of any alternative way of doing this ? I am going crazy over this. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the way is to use the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class and its [after()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#after(java.lang.Object)) , [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [before()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#before(java.lang.Object)) methods.

```
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar anotherDate = Calendar.getInstance();
Date convDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").parse("20-Aug-2013");
anotherDate.setTime(convDate);
if(currentDate .after(anotherDate) || 
   currentDate .equals(anotherDate)){
    System.out.println("Correct");
}else{
   System.out.println("In correct");
}
```

---

You can also use [Jodatime library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) , see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439779/how-to-compare-two-dates-without-the-time-portion).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really good. +1 for the explaino and accepted .

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Date(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) constructor:

```
Date convDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

This way you'll avoid the deprecation warning and will get a Date instance with the system time.

Answer (score 1):

`Date` represents number of milliseconds since the epoch. Why not just use the `Date` returned from

```
Date currentFormattedDate = new Date();
```

?