# How to compare dates in Android app?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, jodatime

Before this question is marked as a duplicate, it's not. I know [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439779/how-to-compare-two-dates-without-the-time-portion), and I tried to use it's answer, to no avail so far.

I've got a date on which some event occurred, and I've got DateTime.now(). I now want to display the words "today" or "yesterday" if the date is today or yesterdays dates. If not (it's further in the past) the date should simply be printed. For this I want to know the difference in days between DateTime.now() and the DateTime at which the event occurred. So I tried this:

```
DateTime actionDate = overviewevent.getActionDate();
Log.wtf(TAG, actionDate.toString()); // Prints 2013-09-06T08:47:04.000+01:00
LocalDate localActionDate = actionDate.toLocalDate();
LocalDate localNow = DateTime.now().toLocalDate();
// First try
Log.wtf(TAG, Integer.toString(localActionDate.compareTo(localNow)));
// Second try
Log.wtf(TAG, Integer.toString(DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance().compare(actionDate, DateTime.now())));
```

Even though there are 10 days between now() and the actionDate, both of the things I try just print "1".

Does anybody know  how I can see how many days the dates are apart?

Comment: What is `DateTime`? This class doesn't seem to be part of the Android API. Also, the `compareTo` method is used for comparison (less, more, same) rather than for difference such as number of days. That's why it prints `1`.

Comment: @DanielGabriel - Excuse me. DateTime is coming from org.joda.time.DateTime;

Comment: Ok, thanks. See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893/number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-joda-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is not printing `1` but `-1`.

The `compare` function just *compares* two dates, it does not compute a time difference. Check the Joda Time [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeComparator.html#compare%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) for more information. Also, I suggest you to read about the more general Java interface [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which is a fundamental unit of the Java language.

I've never used Joda Time so far, but I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893/number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-joda-time) that the solution to your problem might be

```
Days.daysBetween(actionDate.toDateMidnight(), DateTime.now().toDateMidnight()).getDays()
```

Comment: I just tried that, but surprisingly, this now gives me -12256 (even though there are really only 10 days between 2013-09-06 and today (2013-09-16). Any idea why this could be?

Comment: You say today is 2013-09-16 but is your device telling so ? What does `DateTime.now()` print ? This would explain the `1`, maybe..

Comment: Awesome! That was the problem indeed! Thanks a lot!