# Compare a date web element is greater than or equal to current date in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

The date is displayed as Date: November 27, 2021.  I need to ensure this is greater than current date.
Can anyone share code for this plz.

Comment: Please share the code what you have tried.

Comment: I'm new to java and selenium, i have 0 idea of how to go about this at all. So have no code

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726115/comparing-user-input-date-with-current-date

Answer (score 0):

I've obtained what you need with this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter1=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");  
Date coursedate1=formatter1.parse(newdate);  
System.out.println(coursedate1);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");  
Date today = new Date();  
System.out.println(formatter.format(today));
```