# How to check if the timestamp is current date's timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a scheduler that needs to check if the incoming timestamp is current day's timestamp.

The incoming timestamp will be of the format Eg:1384956395.

How to check this in java? Please help. I am not using Joda

Comment: Are you using joda time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1439792/1366360

Answer (score 8):

The epoch you posted is in seconds.  Java uses milliseconds so you have to convert it and then compare the two.

```
long epochInMillis = epoch * 1000;
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar timeToCheck = Calendar.getInstance();
timeToCheck.setTimeInMillis(epochInMillis);

if(now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == timeToCheck.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
    if(now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == timeToCheck.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
    }
}
```

You can also change the time zone if you do not want to use the default, in case the input epoch is in a different time zone.

Comment: Works for me, tnx! I appreciate answers with working code like that easy to test and to import! [btw, you miss a ")" on second if ;)]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your timestamp was created via `System.currentTimeMillis()` (or any other compatible mechanism), you can do the following:

1. Create a `Calendar` instances and set the hour, minute, second and millisecond fields to zero. This is today at 0:00:00,0.
2. Clone the instance and add 1 day. You'll get tomorrow at 0:00:00,0.
3. Now check if your timestamp is in the range between `today.getTime()` (inclusive) and `tomorrow.getTime()` (exclusive).