# issue with comparing two dates in joda time API

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I have a below program to compare two dates.

I get timestamps that are date1   and currentTimestamp, here i need to compare only dates not the time values.But below program always returns -1.(value)

```
timestamp date1 = "2017-01-20 14:51:30.091"  // i get this from service call in this format

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
java.util.Date currentDate = dateFormat.parse(formattedDate);
java.sql.Timestamp currentTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(currentDate.getTime());

int value = DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance().compare(date1 , currentTimestamp );
```

How to compare only dates regardless of time. Please help me on this.

**UPDATED:**

i changed to below code

```
timestamp date1 = "2017-01-20 14:51:30.091"  // i get this from service call in this format
 LocalDate localDate = new LocalDate();
int value = DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance().compare(date1 , localDate );
```

this gives me error saying "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No instant converter found for type: org.joda.time.LocalDate"

Comment: Hmm. To work with Joda time, don't use `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp`. Use [Joda-time classes](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/quickstart.html) *only*.

Comment: maybe I missread this, but where is Joda in the code you posted??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two Dates without the time portion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439779/how-to-compare-two-dates-without-the-time-portion)

Comment: @RealSkeptic I changed to localdate to get current date, but it gives error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No instant converter found for type: org.joda.time.LocalDate"

Comment: Hint: go and built a **real** [mcve] for us please.

Comment: What is `timestamp`? It looks like it's supposed to be a class or type name of some sort, but you're assigning it a string? Please post *real* code. And as was mentioned, a [mcve] would be best.

Answer (score 0):

To compare `DateTime` in `joda` without time you have 2 options:

- convert `DateTime` to `LocalDate` .
- Use `DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance`

For example:

```
@Test
public void compareJodaTime() {
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    String today = "2017-01-20 14:51:30.091";  
    String tomorrow = "2017-01-21 14:51:30.091"; 

    DateTime now = DateTime.now();

    Assert.assertThat(now.toLocalDate().compareTo(DateTime.parse(today, dateTimeFormatter).toLocalDate()), Matchers.is(0));
    Assert.assertThat(now.toLocalDate().compareTo(DateTime.parse(tomorrow, dateTimeFormatter).toLocalDate()), Matchers.is(-1));
    Assert.assertThat(now.toLocalDate().isEqual(DateTime.parse(today, dateTimeFormatter).toLocalDate()), Matchers.is(true));
    Assert.assertThat(now.toLocalDate().isBefore(DateTime.parse(tomorrow, dateTimeFormatter).toLocalDate()), Matchers.is(true));


    Assert.assertThat(DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance().compare(now, DateTime.parse(today, dateTimeFormatter)), Matchers.is(0));
    Assert.assertThat(DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance().compare(now, DateTime.parse(tomorrow, dateTimeFormatter)), Matchers.is(-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT Joda solution...

Use: Apache library 'commons-lang3-x.x.jar' (DateUtils)

```
@Test
public void testCompare() {
 Date current = new Date();
 Date previous = DateUtils.addHours(DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), -1),5);
 assertEquals(1,DateUtils.truncatedCompareTo(current,previous,Calendar.DATE));
 assertEquals(0,DateUtils.truncatedCompareTo(current,current,Calendar.DATE));
 assertEquals(-1,DateUtils.truncatedCompareTo(previous,current,Calendar.DATE));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this code with JodaTime :

    `DateTime date1 = DateTime.parse("2017-01-20 14:51:30.091", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));
    DateTime now = new DateTime();
    int value = DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance().compare(date1 , now);`