# How to check the date part in a Java collection Arraylist?

Tags: list, arraylist, collections

I have one ArrayList:

```
List<Date> date= ArrayList<Date>();
date.add(2017-07-26 09:27:33);
date.add(2017-07-28 10:11:33);
date.add(2017-07-25 08:27:33);
date.add(2017-07-25 07:27:33);
```

Now I am testing

```
date.contains(2017-07-25 11:27:33);     //should come true
```

I want to check on the basis only the only date not time. How can I check only base of date not time?

Comment: That doesn't look like valid Java code to me. Please extract a [mcve]. Anyhow, the definition of a match is pretty simple, so why not simply write the code that scans the list for one?

Comment: my concern know can i compare date only not their time. I just want a approach . validate code not required.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer there could be warning but you put me into negative.Its very sad.

Comment: @Bachas: please do not get into the habit of guessing who has downvoted your question. Voting is anonymous here, except in the cases where people say if and how they voted.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code can not compile.

Lets change it to valid java code and compare two date only without time portion:

```
    List<Date> date = new ArrayList();
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateFormat compareFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

    try {
        date.add(format.parse("2017-07-26 09:27:33"));
        date.add(format.parse("2017-07-28 10:11:33"));
        date.add(format.parse("2017-07-25 08:27:33"));
        date.add(format.parse("2017-07-25 07:27:33"));

        Date searchedDate = format.parse("2017-07-26 16:27:33");

        boolean isExist = date.stream().anyMatch(d -> compareFormat.format(d).equals(compareFormat.format(searchedDate)));


        System.out.println(isExist);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also there are another solutions to compare date without time part, take a look another solutions : [How to compare two Dates without the time portion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439779/how-to-compare-two-dates-without-the-time-portion)