# Check if Date is before today regardless hour

Tags: java, date, datetime, time

I'm trying to compare two Dates in Java, to know if one is before the actual day, but it compares the time too, so regardless is the same day, it says it's before because compares them with the time. Is there any way to just know if the date is before the current day, not the time?

Here is the code I'm using (the date comes from a times

```
long timestampDate = 1623307684;
Date date = new Date((long)timestampDate*1000);
if(date.before(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()))
{
    System.out.println("Was yesterday");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Is today");
}
```

Comment: You can use `LocalDate` class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two Dates without the time portion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439779/how-to-compare-two-dates-without-the-time-portion)

Comment: Reopened it as the duplicate target was not an exact match.  This question differs from the duplicate target for two things: (1) It requires converting the epoch seconds to `Instant`. (2) The duplicate target talks only about the before/after scenario whereas this question also requires finding whether the timestamp refers to ***Yesterday***.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 4):

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>, released in March 2014.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long timestampDate = 1623307684L;
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(timestampDate);

        // Replace JVM's timezone, ZoneId.systemDefault() with the applicable timezone
        // e.g. ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")
        LocalDate date = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        if (date.isBefore(today)) {
            System.out.println("The given timestamp is for a date in the past.");
            // ...
        }

        if (date.equals(today.minusDays(1))) {
            System.out.println("Yesterday");
        }
    }
}
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Hi Arvind Kumar Avinash, thank you for your answer, i'm trying using this timestamp 1623308351, that is today, but earlier, and still saying is yesterday, And in response to your last edit, i don't only need if de date is yesterday, i need to know if is before the actual date. To provide context for this, is to check if the current login on a app is the first one of the day or not.

Comment: @ToastBread - My code has both scenarios: (1) Whether the timestamp refers to a date in the past (2) Whether the timestamp refers to ***Yesterday***. The code does not print ***Yesterday*** as the timestamp is for today's date. Check the output [online](https://ideone.com/cNAC9y). The API is rich with many options. Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Note: This requires API level 26 so probably not suited to most apps or anyone

Comment: @behelit Probably, you missed the footnote. Moreover, [at least 94% of Android apps are on API level 26](https://apilevels.com/).